# Can Bitbucket automatically create issues from code annotations on commits?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I'm looking for a way to automatically create issues within Bitbucket.org for in-code annotations.
E.g. @BUG "Some bug text" should be added as an issue within bitbucket repo when commited.

Comment: Answer from Bitbucket.org Support: "We do have an issue service that you can add to your repository. The details are here http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Setting+Up+the+Bitbucket+Issues+Service

However, the service does not allow you to create issues. There are no other services that would accomplish this for you.

Sorry I could not help more,

Dylan"

Answer (score 2):

This is something that should be handled by a hook, and AFAIK, Bitbucket doesn't support those.

You could keep a local mirror that pulls every now and then (using a cronjob) and in a `changegroup` hook examines the incoming changes, then using [Bitbucket's Issues API](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Issues), creates an issue.

Comment: You may be able to do something like this with the POST service: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Setting+Up+the+Bitbucket+POST+Service (There is also an Issues service, but sadly it only allows updating existing issues, not creating a new one).

Comment: @Wooble: hm, the link I included does have `Creating an Issue`, I haven't tried it though.

Comment: the service automatically makes changes from commit messages. The API allows you to do more stuff, but not directly from your push (although probably using the POST service to run a hook that uses the API would work)

Answer (score 0):

You can discuss and VOTE UP for this feature on [bitbucket tracker - Create an issue from a commit message (BB-5107)](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/4476/create-an-issue-from-a-commit-message-bb)